# scraping data between 2 ul tags

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, html-parsing

hi i am trying to scrape between tags. Below i am attaching a part of the source which i want to scrape. if you look carefully there are 3 ul tag. first ul tag has class = "listGroup". I am trying to extract the second "ul" tag's text using the idea that it is followed by another "ul" tag which has a class "listGroup" . Please share how i can do this.

```
<ul class="listGroup" id="ul_e6d09fbd-19fe-49ac-9b47-bd857c0d411b"><li class="acces-listitems"><a href="https://order.store.mayoclinic.com/books/gnweb43?utm_source=MC-DotOrg-PS&amp;utm_medium=Link&amp;utm_campaign=FamilyHealth-Book&amp;utm_content=FHB">Book: Mayo Clinic Family Health Book, 5th Edition</a></li><li class="acces-hide-listitems"><a href="https://order.store.mayoclinic.com/hl/hldiged?utm_source=MC-DotOrg-PS&amp;utm_medium=Link&amp;utm_campaign=HealthLetter-Digital&amp;utm_content=HLDE">Newsletter: Mayo Clinic Health Letter — Digital Edition</a></li></ul>
<ul>
<li>Osteoporosis</li>
<li>Kidney stones</li>
<li>Excessive urination</li>
<li>Abdominal pain</li>
<li>Tiring easily or weakness</li>
<li>Depression or forgetfulness</li>
<li>Bone and joint pain</li>
<li>Frequent complaints of illness with no apparent cause</li>
<li>Nausea, vomiting or loss of appetite</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>A noncancerous growth (adenoma) on a gland is the most common cause.</li>
<li>Enlargement (hyperplasia) of two or more parathyroid glands accounts for most other cases.</li>
<li>A cancerous tumor is a very rare cause of primary hyperparathyroidism.</li>
</ul>
```

I am attaching the short script i have made so far. Please help .

```
import requests
import pandas
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
for link in ['/diseases-conditions/hyperparathyroidism/symptoms-causes/syc-20356194']:
    page = requests.get(f"https://www.mayoclinic.org{link}")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    for each in soup.find_all("ul"):
        print(each)
```

Comment: You say you are looking for "the second "ul" tag's text using the idea that it is followed by another "ul" tag which has a class "listGroup""; but in your example the third `<ul>` tag has no class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS selector `ul.listGroup + ul li` -> this will select all `<li>` tags of `<ul>` tag next to `<ul>` with class `"listGroup"`:

```
txt = '''<ul class="listGroup" id="ul_e6d09fbd-19fe-49ac-9b47-bd857c0d411b"><li class="acces-listitems"><a href="https://order.store.mayoclinic.com/books/gnweb43?utm_source=MC-DotOrg-PS&amp;utm_medium=Link&amp;utm_campaign=FamilyHealth-Book&amp;utm_content=FHB">Book: Mayo Clinic Family Health Book, 5th Edition</a></li><li class="acces-hide-listitems"><a href="https://order.store.mayoclinic.com/hl/hldiged?utm_source=MC-DotOrg-PS&amp;utm_medium=Link&amp;utm_campaign=HealthLetter-Digital&amp;utm_content=HLDE">Newsletter: Mayo Clinic Health Letter — Digital Edition</a></li></ul>

<ul>
<li>Osteoporosis</li>
<li>Kidney stones</li>
<li>Excessive urination</li>
<li>Abdominal pain</li>
<li>Tiring easily or weakness</li>
<li>Depression or forgetfulness</li>
<li>Bone and joint pain</li>
<li>Frequent complaints of illness with no apparent cause</li>
<li>Nausea, vomiting or loss of appetite</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>A noncancerous growth (adenoma) on a gland is the most common cause.</li>
<li>Enlargement (hyperplasia) of two or more parathyroid glands accounts for most other cases.</li>
<li>A cancerous tumor is a very rare cause of primary hyperparathyroidism.</li>
</ul>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for li in soup.select('ul.listGroup + ul li'):
    print(li.text)
```

Prints:

```
Osteoporosis
Kidney stones
Excessive urination
Abdominal pain
Tiring easily or weakness
Depression or forgetfulness
Bone and joint pain
Frequent complaints of illness with no apparent cause
Nausea, vomiting or loss of appetite
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a natural use case for a CSS selector, namely:

`ul.listGroup + ul li` will select all of the `li` tags in the first `ul` tag that follows each `ul` tag with the class `listGroup`. Replacing `+` with `~` will instead select all of the `li` tags in all (in this case 2) `ul` tags that follow each tag with the class `listGroup`.

To implement this answer in your script replace `find_all` with `select` and update the selector with the relevant CSS selector.

```py
import requests
import pandas
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
for link in ['/diseases-conditions/hyperparathyroidism/symptoms-causes/syc-20356194']:
    page = requests.get(f"https://www.mayoclinic.org{link}")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    for each in soup.select("ul.listGroup + ul li"):
        print(each.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider using a regular expression to make a capture.